# How to stick text to line on font resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There's a design issue I'd like to fix in my app, whenever some text is resized it doesn't stick to the same place. Either way the font moves up if its size gets smaller or down when the size is bigger. It doesn't stay in the same place, I'd like the origin to be on the bottom left of the font.

**Here's a schema of what I want to achieve:**

[image]

I've added a line in the snippet, the font should always be exactly on top of the line whenever font size changes (note that the line is just here to help, it is not here in my app).

**`p` should stay on `absolute` position.**

**Try snippet to see the problem :**

```js
$('.opt-minus').click(function() {
  var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
  var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
  count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
  $input.val(count);
  $input.change();
  return false;
});

$('.opt-plus').click(function() {
  var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
  $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
  $input.change();
  return false;
});

$(document).on('change', '#tb-font-size', function() {
  var content = $(this).val();
  $('p').css({
    "font-size": content + 'px',
  })
});
```

```css
.btn {
    line-height: 36px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: white;
    color: #ecf0f1;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 1px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  }
  
  input {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border: solid 1px #eaeaea;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: all ease .3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease .3s;
    -ms-transition: all ease .3s;
    -o-transition: all ease .3s;
    transition: all ease .3s;
  }
  
  .tb-opt-int {
    height: 40px;
    width: 158px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  p {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:30px;
  }
  .absolute {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>How to make it scale from bottom left ?</h3>
<div class="tb-opt-int">
  <span class="opt-minus btn">-</span>
  <input id="tb-font-size" type="text" class="tb-select" name="tb-fonts-size" value="16">
  <span class="opt-plus btn">+</span>
</div>
<div style="position:relative;">
  <p>Scaling from <strong>top left</strong> cross origin</p>

  <span class="absolute" style="top: 40px;"></span>
</div>
```

Is there anyway to fix this issue with Javascript or CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are using `top`, the top of the text will always be at the same place.  You could use `bottom` instead.

**Update:** Based on the comments, you can modify the `top` with JavaScript at the same time you modify the `font-size` so that the top will move up with a larger font size and down with a smaller font.

```js
$('.opt-minus').click(function() {
  var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
  var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
  count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
  $input.val(count);
  $input.change();
  return false;
});

$('.opt-plus').click(function() {
  var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
  $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
  $input.change();
  return false;
});

$(document).on('change', '#tb-font-size', function() {
  var content = $(this).val();
  var current_top = $(".scaling-p").position().top;
  var bottom = current_top + $(".scaling-p").height();
  var height =  $(".scaling-p").height();
  $('p').css({
    "font-size": content + 'px',
  }).css({
    top: (current_top - ((current_top +  $(".scaling-p").height()) - bottom)) + 'px'
  })
});
```

```css
.btn {
    line-height: 36px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: white;
    color: #ecf0f1;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 1px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  }
  
  input {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border: solid 1px #eaeaea;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: all ease .3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease .3s;
    -ms-transition: all ease .3s;
    -o-transition: all ease .3s;
    transition: all ease .3s;
  }
  
  .tb-opt-int {
    height: 40px;
    width: 158px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  p {
    position:absolute;
    top:22px;
    left:30px;
    margin:0;
    line-height: 1em;
  }
  .absolute {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>How to make it scale from bottom left ?</h3>
<div class="tb-opt-int">
  <span class="opt-minus btn">-</span>
  <input id="tb-font-size" type="text" class="tb-select" name="tb-fonts-size" value="16">
  <span class="opt-plus btn">+</span>
</div>
<div style="position:relative;">
  <p class="scaling-p">Scaling from <strong>top left</strong> cross origin</p>

  <span class="absolute" style="top: 40px;"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do but isn't there a way to do this using Javascript ? and not Using bottom `element`?

Comment: Sure, I'll update my answer.  You would want the top to be at 10px when the font-size is 16px ?

Comment: Everything can be different, top can be from 1 to 1000px and font-size may vary too, the one I showed is just an example

Comment: I updated the code, but this will not work once it gets to multi-line.  I will update again.

Comment: The problem is that this works only when the top is at certain value... what if the top is at 420px or 160px or something else ?

Comment: I have updated again.  You can set any top you like to start and it will also take into consideration multi-line.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I just tried it on jsfiddle and don't have the same result as the snippet, https://jsfiddle.net/ervn1wtv/9/ I was wondering what was causing this issue

Comment: I updated your answer, you shouldn't parseInt values otherwise it won't be precise, and don't use $(...).css(); to get values but $(...).position().top so you don't have to parse it.